# Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.1.6.RELEASE' not found

Tags: spring-boot, maven, email, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm running a spring boot app and everything was working just fine, but when I added the **spring-boot-starter-mail** dependency in my pom.xml file, it is failing to download this dependency and it is highlighted in red.
I want to use the JavaMailSender to send emails in the application.

> ERROR: **Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.1.6.RELEASE' not found**
> [image]

> **Code snippet to send an email below:**
> [image]

These are the versions I am working with:

- Java 1.8
- Springboot 2.1.6
- Dev Environment: IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2

**Complete pom.xml file below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyWebApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-data-version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring-data-version>
        <hibernate-version>5.3.6.Final</hibernate-version>
        <mysql.version>8.0.16</mysql.version>
        <spring-session-bom.version>Bean-SR6</spring-session-bom.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>${sun-mail.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-session-bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please post more information about the failure... where have you built? How have you built??? Also you are mixing several spring boot versions and spring/hibernate?

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise I have edited my question to add more details, hope that helps. And also, is it better not to specify versions so that I don't get them mixed up?

Comment: Have you tried to build on plain command line...? And yes you should leave the versions to spring boot instead of defining of your own...for hibernate/lombok etc. apart from that the used version of spring boot is simply out of date...upgrade!

Comment: Okay duly noted. Let me try upgrading spring boot and removing the dependancy versions.

Comment: @khmarbaise your suggestions worked, thanks a lot.
I also had to reset my settings.xml file because it had some proxy settings that were preventing me from downloading some dependencies.

Comment: BTW: I would also suggest to upgrade your IDE version...

Comment: I've thought about that. I'll be upgrading my IDE version soon thanks